# Running a process as sudo in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to run a process as sudo in scala. I have written this code

```
  val l : Seq[String] = Seq("echo", "SecretXYZ!", "|", "sudo", "-S", "-u", "web", "spark-submit", "--class",
    "com.abhi.Foo", "--master", "yarn-cluster", "Foo-assembly-1.0.jar", DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).print(date), ">",
    "fn_output.txt", "2>", "fn_error.txt")
  l.!
  println("completed...")
```

but when I run this, it doesn't run the process. it just prints

```
SecretXYZ! | sudo -S -u web spark-submit --class com.abhi.Foo --master yarn-cluster Foo-assembly-1.0.jar 2015-03-19 > fn_output.txt 2> fn_error.txt
completed...
```

Comment: Presumably `!` doesn't pass things to a shell, so "|"  (and ">" and ">2") are just more arguments to `echo`.

Comment: and how do I change this?

Comment: Use `#|` `#>` operators. See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/sys/process/package.html

Answer (score 1):

As Łukasz has pointed out, the "right" answer is to build the pipeline yourself with `sys.process`.

The lazy answer is to explicitly wrap everything in a call to `bash -c ...`:

```
val miniScript: Seq[String] = Seq(
  "echo", "SecretXYZ!",
  "|", "sudo", "-S", "-u", "web",
  "spark-submit", "--class", "com.abhi.Foo", "--master", "yarn-cluster",
  "Foo-assembly-1.0.jar", DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).print(date),
  ">", "fn_output.txt", "2>", "fn_error.txt")

val cmd: Seq[String] = Seq("bash", "-c", miniScript.mkString(" "))

cmd.!
```

Be careful with escaping, though -- your password in this version would need single-quotes around it, for example -- and really, if you want this code to be robust, you should really do it with `sys.process` so you know exactly what's happening.